# Steps to help design the system v.s. Steps to help the system design?

Tags: verbs

Are both correct? There is a difference between them?
Cheers!

Comment: They're both correct.  They mean different things.  Are you helping *design* the verb or *design* the noun?

Comment: Ok @HotLicks, good question! thank you, was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first makes more sense than the second, although both are grammatically correct. The issue is that 'the system design' is an outline, or a template, or an intended architecture. It's not logical for anyone or anything to be able to *assist* such an abstract thing.
This idea would be better expressed as 'Steps to improve the system design'.